# How to add allowed relay IPs for Windows SMTP using command line or script

Tags: windows, smtp, email-server, scripting, vbscript

I have a long list of IP addresses I need to add as allowed relays to the built-in SMTP service on Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5, but SMTP uses the old IIS 6.0 manager)

I know how to add allowed relays manually, but there is quite a long list so I'm looking to automate it.

Is there any way to do this from the command line, a script or some other automation?

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I can't fix the question if I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Might have been downvoted because it is fairly google-able...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS 6 SMTP server?  The config for this is in the IIS metabase XML file at `systemroot\system32\inetserv\metabase.xml`
Line: RelayIpList

VBS to set relay IPs:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objSMTP,objRelayIpList,objCurrentList,objIP,objFSO,objTextFile,count,newIpList(),inputOption
Set objSMTP = GetObject("IIS://localhost/smtpsvc/1")
Set objRelayIpList = objSMTP.Get("RelayIpList") 
'objRelayIpList is of type IIsIPSecuritySetting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525725.aspx
Wscript.Echo "============================================" 
Wscript.Echo "CURRENT SETTINGS"
Wscript.Echo "================"
Wscript.Echo " " 
Wscript.Echo "Computer(s) that may relay through this virtual server."
Wscript.Echo " " 
' GrantByDefault returns 0 when "only the list below" is set (false) and -1 when all except the list below is set(true)
If objRelayIpList.GrantByDefault = true Then
    Wscript.Echo "All except the list below :"
    objCurrentList = objRelayIpList.IPDeny
Else 
    Wscript.Echo "Only the list below :"
    objCurrentList = objRelayIpList.IPGrant
End If
count = 0
For Each objIP in objCurrentList
        Wscript.Echo objIP 
        count = count + 1
Next
If count = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "*NIL*"
End If
Wscript.Echo "============================================" 
Wscript.Echo " " 
Wscript.Echo "Replacing ReplayIpList with the IP address(es) from the ip.txt file."
Wscript.Echo " "
Do While Not((inputOption = "a") Or (inputOption = "d") Or (inputOption = "x") ) 
Wscript.Echo "ENTER " 
Wscript.Echo "A to add to Allow List (Only the list below)"
Wscript.Echo "D to add to Deny List (All except the list below)"
Wscript.Echo "X Exit without making changes"
Wscript.Echo " "
inputOption = lcase(trim(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine))
Loop
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FileExists("ip.txt") Then
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("ip.txt",1)

    count = 0
    Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
        Redim Preserve newIpList(count)
        newIpList(count) = objTextFile.Readline
        count = count + 1
    Loop
    objTextFile.Close

    'For each objIP in newIpList
    '    Wscript.Echo objIP
    'Next
    Wscript.Echo " "
    Select Case inputOption
        Case "a"
            objRelayIpList.GrantByDefault = false
            objRelayIpList.IpGrant = newIpList
            Wscript.Echo "SET " & count &" address(es) to Allow List"        
        Case "d"
            objRelayIpList.GrantByDefault = true
            objRelayIpList.IpDeny = newIpList
            Wscript.Echo "SET " & count &" address(es) to Deny List"
        Case "x"
            Wscript.Echo "Exiting without making changes"
            Wscript.Echo "============================================" 
            Wscript.Quit
    End Select

    objSMTP.Put "RelayIpList",objRelayIpList
    objSMTP.SetInfo
    Wscript.Echo " "

    Wscript.Echo "============================================" 
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Please create a file ip.txt that contains the list of IP address(es)"
    Wscript.Echo "FORMAT : Each Line should be IP,MASK "
    Wscript.Echo "EX     : 127.0.0.1,255.255.255.255"
End If
```

Credits:

```
 Script to Import a bunch of IP addresses to the ReplayIpList             

                     (c)vijaysk@microsoft.com                             
                     blogs.msdn.com/vijaysk                               


 USAGE : cscript ImportRelayList.vbs                                      
 PREREQUISITE : This script needs ip.txt in the same folder.              
 Store your IP addresses in ip.txt FORMAT: Each line should be IP,MASK
```

From: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/05/07/setting-smtp-relayiplist-from-a-script.aspx

Untested by me (BlueCompute)

Comment: Yes it's IIS 6, I'll update the question with that